# how to use a conditional statement to stop a code with several inputs?

Tags: if-statement

I wrote a code and want to end it after the first input is equal to "done".
If I write the condition after all of the inputs, the user should answer all the useless questions.
On the other hand, I don't want to write the condition in the middle of the inputs as you see in the following part.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.

Here is the code:

```
while True:

ind1=input('please enter your personal number:')
if ind1=='done':
    break
ind2=input('please enter your name:')
ind3=input('please enter your family name:')
ind4=int(input('please enter your working hours:'))
ind5=int(input('please enter your payment:'))
```

Comment: `On the other hand, I don't want to write the condition in the middle of the inputs as you see in the following part.` why not?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple variables, use an array.
pseudo code:

```
inputs = []
count = 0
while true:
  if inputs[count] == 'done': break
  inputs[count] = input('...')
  count++
```

Comment: he will need a questions array, too

Comment: Yeah that's true